ArcGIS "Buffered"/Blurry Point Symbol
I have a point layer with oscillating confidence in their correct location (1-5) and want to style them representing this fuzziness.
In a storymap, I found a symbology with radially increasing transparency that appeals to me as a model, but I have no idea how to reproduce it (or to vary it by my fuzzy indicator): https://storymaps.arcgis.com/stories/e62e9bf65f2340599671150dc735dee3

I do not seek a solution with fixed buffer, like converting the points into polygons, but rather something handled by symbology.

John Nelson at Esri created a "firefly" style that can be downloaded and added to your ArcGIS Pro project - the point symbology looks similar to the one in that StoryMap. You can download the .stylx file here and read his blog post about the style here.
